# Exception: Segmentation Error when assigning variable

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

My code compiles fine and gives the wanted outcome when I run it,
but if I want to debug it, there is a segmentation Error in this line:
(Sorry for German variable names)

```
(*pointer)[0]->gehalt = 2000;
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's wrong?

```
void add_record(Person ***pointer, int *lenght){

*lenght+= 1;

//allocate one new Person struct pointer or create the first one
if(*pointer == NULL)
    *pointer = malloc(1 * sizeof(Person*));
else
    *pointer = realloc(*pointer, (*lenght) * sizeof(Person*));

//return if realloc failed
if(*pointer == NULL){
    printf("No more Space available\n");
    return;
}

//give pointer the new value of the adress of array-pointer
pointer = &(*pointer);

//give the variable a value
(*pointer)[0]->gehalt = 2000;

//print the value
printf("gehalt: %d", (*pointer)[0]->gehalt);
}
```

The main function to my program:

```
int main(){
Person *(*array) = NULL;

Person ***pointer = &array;
int lenght = 0;

add_record(pointer, &lenght);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really need some help here please.
I have no Idea whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you appear to lack basic understanding of pointers. This:

> `pointer = &(*pointer);`

does *absolutely nothing*. You also have too many levels of indirection, and you never allocate space for the `Person` itself, only for a pointer to one.

I suggest you start with this (correct) code, understand what it does, and then modify it to actually do what you need.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int gehalt;
} Person;

void add_record(Person **ptr, int *length)
{
  if (*ptr == NULL) 
    *ptr = malloc(sizeof(Person));
  else
    *ptr = realloc(*ptr, (*length + 1) * sizeof(Person));

  (*ptr + *length)->gehalt = 2000 + *length;
  *length += 1;
}

int main()
{
  Person *array = NULL;
  int length = 0;

  add_record(&array, &length);
  add_record(&array, &length);
  add_record(&array, &length);

  for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
    printf("%d: %d\n", j, array[j].gehalt);
  }

  return 0;
}
```